# Can't dynamically add fragment if it's inside ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I'm trying to dynamically add a fragment to my XML layout. The layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rellayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:name="com.amaj.notetakertest.TopSectionFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="359dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragment1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I'm trying to dynamically add another fragment (call it fragment2) to `rellayout1` inside the `ScrollView`, as seen above. But the app crashes when fragment2 is dynamically added.

The crash doesn't happen if I remove the ScrollView from the layout and then dynamically add the fragment to `rellayout1`. Nor does it happen if I dynamically add the fragment to other Layouts outside the ScrollView. My question is: What is it about ScrollView that causes the dysfunction?

The code for dynamically adding the fragment is as follows:

```
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rellayout1);

    TopSectionFragment f = new TopSectionFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fTrans = fm.beginTransaction();
    fTrans.add(rl.getId(), f);
    fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
    fTrans.commit();
```

The above Java code runs when a click event happens.

Just to clarify, the TopSectionFragment class does extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, and everything in the class is otherwise fine. I can add the fragment perfectly well to other layouts. It's just that whenever I try to add it within a layout that's **inside** a ScrollView, it crashes. Tried it independently with other tests apps as well. It's also not the lack of LayoutParams I think, because the problem persists even if I add LayoutParams.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Here's the log:

```
05-01 21:32:29.010 27452-27469/com.amaj.notetakertest E/EGL_emulation: tid 
27469: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
05-01 21:32:33.207 27452-27452/com.amaj.notetakertest E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.amaj.notetakertest, PID: 27452
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:877)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:856)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:823)
    at com.amaj.notetakertest.CanvasView.onSizeChanged(CanvasView.java:46)
    at android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:17641)
    at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:17603)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1535)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Based on the log, it seems that there's a problem when the onSizedChanged() method is called in the CanvasView class, which is a canvas that's in the fragment's layout.

The method in the CanvasView class is as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}
```

And the addition of the CanvasView into the fragment is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <com.amaj.notetakertest.CanvasView
        android:id="@+id/signature_canvas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could u post your log as well??

Comment: Please post your crash log from logcat.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I just did.

Comment: Try to make a `LinearLayout` after your `RelativeLayout`, and use `add()` method from FragmentManager on it, instead to use it on your `RelativeLayout`. (To sum it up, add your fragment to a separate LinearLayout)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is

Parent Layout ↓

```
<RelativeLayout>
```

Then you add Toolbar ↓

```
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>
```

Then ScrollView ↓

```
                     <ScrollView/>
```

And Last your required page Layout ↓

```
                                 <RelativeLayout/>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how Toolbar is relevant here.

Comment: I've added it to help you better understanding if want to include in the future,if my answer helped you please mark it as one